# Matlab control parameters settings

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am missing a setting in Matlab 2018b which I have in Matlab 2012b(32 bits).

[image: settings window]

The setting which I am missing is "Mux blocks used to create bus signals". Any ideas on how to add this setting to my current Matlab version?

I tried going into Analysis->Model Advisor ->Upgrade Advisors and looked through the options listed there but couldn't find what I wanted.

Comment: I do not know about this option, but maybe you can use a [bus creator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/buscreator.html) to do what you want.

Comment: I need to use a demux because i am working with arrays